# how to solve Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm not able to perform the routing with the parameter, I'm getting the error `cant read property 'name'`. I used the template engine `twig`.
Here is my template,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{About}}</title>
</head>
<body>
   <P><h1>{{user}}</h1></P>
   <P><h2>{{text}}</h2></P>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my main 'js' file-

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()

app.use('./static',express.static('twig templet'))
app.set('view engine', 'twig')
app.set('views','./twig templet/views')

app.get('/',(res,req)=>{
    req.render('index',{title:'EXPRESS',gred:'Hello-welcome to Express',mes:'This is twig file'})

})

app.get('/about/:name',(res,req)=>{
    res.render('about',{About:'User',user:req.params.name,text:'This is twig file'})
    console.log('user is:'+ req.params.name)
 
})

app.get('/calculation/:a-:b',(res,req)=>{
    res.render('calculator',
    {About1:'Calculation',
    add:parseInt(req.params.a) + parseInt(req.params.b),
    sub:parseInt(req.params.a) - parseInt(req.params.b),
    mul:parseInt(req.params.a) * parseInt(req.params.b),
    div:parseInt(req.params.a) / parseInt(req.params.b)})


    //console.log('user is:'+ res.params.Name)

})

app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("server is running at 5000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the callback values from the app.get() in the wrong order, it should be like this, you can omit the `next` though,

`app.get('/about/:name',(req, res, next) => {}`

That's it.